# Handle error event (when loading fails) of smartgwt's Img object

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I need to load an image without knowing if the image is available. Specifically, I load an image by some ID (eg. `123.png`), but only certain ID's have the images.

One solution which seems pretty straightforward is to set the `onerror` event on the `<img>` tag. If it fires, set the URL of the image to something static, eg. `no_image.png`.

I know how to do this with HTML/JavaScript, but I have no idea how to do it with `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Img`. How to add the error event listener?

Comment: You can also ask GWT questions from GWT developers here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt